# why datatable change the format of date

Tags: sql, vb.net

In the following code, I am facing an issue such that in SQL the STDATE is stored in datetime2 type, but its format gets changed when called via DataTable in vb.net.

For example: when the date in the database is "2020-02-05 11:32:47.0000000" it changes to #2/5/2020 11:32:47 AM#.

My requirement is to add months and days in the date from the server but when I add the month to it, it adds days instead of months[sic]. So I need the date to be of the same format as in SQL

```vb
Dim STDATE As Date
        'Dim STDATE1 As String = ""
        'Dim STDATE2 As String = ""
        Dim STMONTH As Integer
        Dim STMONDIFF As Integer
        Dim CTY As String = ""
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim J As Integer

        'Dim DPT2 As DateTime = DTP2.Value
        CASVW()
        Dim CASVWDT As New DataTable
        CASVWDT = CASVWDS.Tables(0)

        If CASVWDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            J = CASVWDT.Rows.Count - 1
            For I = 0 To J
                If CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_CaseAbNo").ToString = TB1.Text Then
                    INSTN = CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_NoOfInst").ToString
                    INSTAMT = CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_InstAmt").ToString
                    STDATE = CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_Date")
                    STMONTH = Month(CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_InstStartDate"))
                    CTY = CASVWDT.Rows(I)("Case_PayType").ToString
                End If
            Next
        End If
        STMONDIFF = STMONTH - Month(STDATE)
        STDATE = STDATE.AddMonths(STMONDIFF)
        'STDATE1 = STDATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00")

        Dim CBSTR1 As String = "SELECT * FROM TB_CASEINST WHERE CaseInst_CaseUniq='" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "'"
        Dim CBDA1 As New SqlDataAdapter(CBSTR1, CN)
        Dim CBDT1 As New DataTable
        CBDA1.Fill(CBDT1)
        CBDA1.Dispose()

        If CBDT1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            Dim Z As Integer
            Dim INSTSTR As String = ""
            Dim CINSTSTR As String = ""
            Dim CASEINSTSTR As String = ""
            Dim CASEINSTSTR1 As String = ""
            Dim CINSTUNIQ As Guid
            Dim GURU1 As Long = TB3.Text
            Dim GURU2 As Long = TB4.Text
            Dim GURU As Long = GURU1 + GURU2

            CASEINSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInstD] ([CaseInstDUniq],[CaseInstD_OrgUniq],[CaseInstD_CaseUniq],[CaseInstD_InstUniq],[CaseInstDTranDueDate],[CaseInstDAmt],[CaseInstDBalAmt],[CaseInstDStatus],[CaseInstDRemks],[CaseInstDChqNo],[CaseInstDBankName],[CaseInstDChqDate],[CaseInstDChqAmt],[CaseInstDDate],[CaseInstDIsActive],[CaseInstDTransType],[CaseInstDPAmt],[CaseInstDInttAmt],[CaseInstDType])" _
                         & "VALUES ('" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & TB3.Text & "," & TB3.Text & ",'D','Loan Amount','" & TB6.Text & "','" & CB2.Text & "','" & DTP2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") & "'," & TB3.Text & ",'" & SRDATE & "','A'," & CASEI & "," & TB3.Text & "," & TB4.Text & ",'L')"
            Dim CASEINSTCMD As New SqlCommand(CASEINSTSTR, CN)
            CASEINSTCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            CASEINSTCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CASEINSTCMD.Dispose()

            CASEINSTSTR1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInstD] ([CaseInstDUniq],[CaseInstD_OrgUniq],[CaseInstD_CaseUniq],[CaseInstD_InstUniq],[CaseInstDTranDueDate],[CaseInstDAmt],[CaseInstDBalAmt],[CaseInstDStatus],[CaseInstDRemks],[CaseInstDChqNo],[CaseInstDBankName],[CaseInstDChqDate],[CaseInstDChqAmt],[CaseInstDDate],[CaseInstDIsActive],[CaseInstDTransType],[CaseInstDPAmt],[CaseInstDInttAmt],[CaseInstDType])" _
             & "VALUES ('" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & TB4.Text & "," & GURU & ",'D','Intt Amount','" & TB6.Text & "','" & CB2.Text & "','" & DTP2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") & "'," & TB3.Text & ",'" & SRDATE & "','A'," & CASEI & "," & TB3.Text & "," & TB4.Text & ",'L')"
            Dim CASEINSTCMD1 As New SqlCommand(CASEINSTSTR1, CN)
            CASEINSTCMD1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            CASEINSTCMD1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CASEINSTCMD1.Dispose()

            I = 0
            For Z = 0 To INSTN - 1
                If CTY = "M" Then
                    STDATE = STDATE.AddMonths(I)
                    'STDATE2 = STDATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:01")
                    PAMTPART = Math.Round(TB3.Text / INSTN, 2)
                    INTAMTPART = Math.Round(TB4.Text / INSTN, 2)
                    CINSTUNIQ = Guid.NewGuid()
                    INSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInst] ([CaseInstUniq],[CaseInst_OrgUniq],[CaseInst_CaseUniq],[CaseInstDueDate],[CaseInstAmount], [CaseInstBalAmt],[CaseInstStatus],[CaseInstRemks],[CaseInstDate],[CaseInstPAmt],[CaseInstInttAmt],[IsActive])" _
                                & "VALUES ('" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','" & SRDATE & "'," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'A')"
                    CINSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInstD] ([CaseInstDUniq],[CaseInstD_OrgUniq],[CaseInstD_CaseUniq],[CaseInstD_InstUniq],[CaseInstDTranDueDate],[CaseInstDAmt],[CaseInstDBalAmt],[CaseInstDStatus],[CaseInstDRemks],[CaseInstDChqNo],[CaseInstDBankName],[CaseInstDChqDate],[CaseInstDChqAmt],[CaseInstDDate],[CaseInstDIsActive],[CaseInstDTransType],[CaseInstDPAmt],[CaseInstDInttAmt],[CaseInstDType])" _
                                             & "VALUES ('" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','XX','XX','" & SRDATE & "',0,'" & SRDATE & "','A'," & CASEI & "," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'I')"
                    I = 1
                ElseIf CTY = "D" Then
                    STDATE = STDATE.AddDays(I)
                    'STDATE2 = STDATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:01")
                    PAMTPART = Math.Round(TB3.Text / INSTN, 2)
                    CINSTUNIQ = Guid.NewGuid()
                    INTAMTPART = Math.Round(TB4.Text / INSTN, 2)
                    INSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInst] ([CaseInstUniq],[CaseInst_OrgUniq],[CaseInst_CaseUniq],[CaseInstDueDate],[CaseInstAmount], [CaseInstBalAmt],[CaseInstStatus],[CaseInstRemks],[CaseInstDate],[CaseInstPAmt],[CaseInstInttAmt],[IsActive])" _
                                                     & "VALUES ('" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','" & SRDATE & "'," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'A')"
                    CINSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInstD] ([CaseInstDUniq],[CaseInstD_OrgUniq],[CaseInstD_CaseUniq],[CaseInstD_InstUniq],[CaseInstDTranDueDate],[CaseInstDAmt],[CaseInstDBalAmt],[CaseInstDStatus],[CaseInstDRemks],[CaseInstDChqNo],[CaseInstDBankName],[CaseInstDChqDate],[CaseInstDChqAmt],[CaseInstDDate],[CaseInstDIsActive],[CaseInstDTransType],[CaseInstDPAmt],[CaseInstDInttAmt],[CaseInstDType])" _
                                             & "VALUES ('" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','XX','XX','" & SRDATE & "',0,'" & SRDATE & "','A'," & CASEI & "," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'I')"
                    I = 1
                ElseIf CTY = "W" Then
                    STDATE = STDATE.AddDays(I)
                    'STDATE2 = STDATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:01")
                    PAMTPART = Math.Round((TB3.Text / INSTN), 2) * 7
                    CINSTUNIQ = Guid.NewGuid()
                    INTAMTPART = Math.Round((TB4.Text / INSTN), 2) * 7
                    INSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInst] ([CaseInstUniq],[CaseInst_OrgUniq],[CaseInst_CaseUniq],[CaseInstDueDate],[CaseInstAmount], [CaseInstBalAmt],[CaseInstStatus],[CaseInstRemks],[CaseInstDate],[CaseInstPAmt],[CaseInstInttAmt],[IsActive])" _
                                                     & "VALUES ('" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','" & SRDATE & "'," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'A')"
                    CINSTSTR = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_CaseInstD] ([CaseInstDUniq],[CaseInstD_OrgUniq],[CaseInstD_CaseUniq],[CaseInstD_InstUniq],[CaseInstDTranDueDate],[CaseInstDAmt],[CaseInstDBalAmt],[CaseInstDStatus],[CaseInstDRemks],[CaseInstDChqNo],[CaseInstDBankName],[CaseInstDChqDate],[CaseInstDChqAmt],[CaseInstDDate],[CaseInstDIsActive],[CaseInstDTransType],[CaseInstDPAmt],[CaseInstDInttAmt],[CaseInstDType])" _
                                             & "VALUES ('" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "','" & ORGUNQ.ToString & "','" & CSUNIQ.ToString & "','" & CINSTUNIQ.ToString & "','" & STDATE & "'," & INSTAMT & "," & INSTAMT & ",'D','Inst. Due','XX','XX','" & SRDATE & "',0,'" & SRDATE & "','A'," & CASEI & "," & PAMTPART & "," & INTAMTPART & ",'I')"
                    I = 6
                    Z = Z + 6
                    If Z >= 100 Then
                        INSTAMT = INSTAMT - (INSTAMT / 7)
                    End If
                End If

                Dim INSTCMD As New SqlCommand(INSTSTR, CN)
                INSTCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                INSTCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                INSTCMD.Dispose()

                Dim CINSTCMD As New SqlCommand(CINSTSTR, CN)
                CINSTCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                CINSTCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CINSTCMD.Dispose()
            Next
```

Comment: Dates don't have a format, format is only applied when the value is shown on screen

Comment: Then how should i use it as it add days if i add months to it.because the format is changed when fetched from datatable

Comment: Use a DateTime object, don't convert it to string in the first place. You only specify a Format when you need to **present** the DateTime in a UI, using the CurrentCulture/User settings or whatever format your app is supposed to use or whatever format its User has chosen. You only work with the DateTime object (or, even better, a DateTimeOffset) *behind the scene*.

Comment: I am new to vb.net and i am unaware how to pass datatable value to datetime obejct and then add months to it.

Comment: You just need to declare your `STDATE` (and `STMONTH`, probably) as Date variables, not strings. Then provide a specific Format when you need to present these values. The `ToString()` method is often used to convert the DateTime object to a string representation. Also, note that in your `For I = 0 To J` loop, you're overwriting the same variables on each iteration, so, in the end, you'll only have the last record value stored in those variables (this is not how you handle a DataTable, anyway).

Comment: both are defined as date and value is directly pass from the datatable to STDATE but i am unable to add month because when month is added it actually add the date not the month

Comment: Those variables were not both declared as `DateTime`, of course. You just edited the code in your question, you were using `ToString()` before (if you don't have `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On`, then set them both before you do anything else, possibly in Visual Studio's general options, so you'll have them pre-set in any new Project). If you have a `Date` variable/Field, you just need e.g., `STDATE = STDATE.AddMonths(1)` to add a month to the current date. If you use strings, you have more than one problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, might shed some light on your Problem, hope it helps.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strSQLconn As String = "Your Connectionstring"
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strSQLconn)
    Dim Command As SqlCommand
    Command = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(1) convert(varchar, [date], 23) FROM [dbo].[Element]", sqlConn)

    Dim x As String
    sqlConn.Open()
    x = Command.ExecuteScalar()
    sqlConn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("SQL Date Converted to String: " & x)

    Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    MessageBox.Show("VB.net string Converted to Date: " & d.ToString)

    MessageBox.Show("VB.net string Converted to Date, and an additional 1 month: " & d.AddMonths(1).ToString)
End Sub
```